# How to clean survey data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

**Input:**

[image]
**Output:**

[image]

**here's the data:**

`d = {'Morning': ["Didn't answer",   "Didn't answer",   "Didn't answer",   'Morning',   "Didn't answer"], 'Afternoon': ["Didn't answer",   'Afternoon',   "Didn't answer",   'Afternoon',   "Didn't answer"], 'Night': ["Didn't answer",   'Night',   "Didn't answer",   'Night',   'Night'], 'Sporadic': ["Didn't answer",   "Didn't answer",   'Sporadic',   "Didn't answer",   "Didn't answer"], 'Constant': ["Didn't answer",   "Didn't answer",   "Didn't answer",   'Constant',   "Didn't answer"]}`

```
         Morning      Afternoon          Night       Sporadic       Constant
0  Didn't answer  Didn't answer  Didn't answer  Didn't answer  Didn't answer
1  Didn't answer      Afternoon          Night  Didn't answer  Didn't answer
2  Didn't answer  Didn't answer  Didn't answer       Sporadic  Didn't answer
3        Morning      Afternoon          Night  Didn't answer       Constant
4  Didn't answer  Didn't answer          Night  Didn't answer  Didn't answer
```

**I want the output to be:**

`d = {"Time of the day": ["Didn't answer", "['Afternoon', 'Night']", "Sporadic", "['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Night', 'Constant']",  "Night"]}`

```
                                 Time of the day
0                                  Didn't answer
1                         ['Afternoon', 'Night']
2                                       Sporadic
3  ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Night', 'Constant']
4                                          Night
```

so if there's no answer in every column in a row, the value in the new data frame would be "Didn't answer"
and if there's at least one answer like "night", the value in the new data frame would be "night"
and if there are multiple answers like " Morning", "Night" the value in the new data frame would be a list of the answers

Comment: `I want the output to be:` check your second data it gives dataframe as what I have posted, are you sure is this what you expect?

Comment: Also the first data dict you posted gives weird dataframe  check that out by reading using pd.DataFrame

Comment: yes, this is what I expect, the data isn't tidy, so I want to tidy it up so that all the values are stored in one column. I have been at it for some time creating for loops and list comprehensions but I can't get it right. also every row is one person(Observation).

Comment: check out both the datframes, I updated the question. By what logic are you converting df1 to df2

Comment: first i want to create a new column "Time of the day", I want to iterate over every row value if all values in a row are "Didn't answer", Then I add "Didn't answer" to the new column for that row, And if there are other values in a row other than "Didn't answer" I add those values to a list inside the new column., if you have a better suggestion please share, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df["ToD"] = (df.replace("Didn't answer", np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0)
               .apply(lambda x: [i for i in x] if len(x) > 1 else x.iloc[0])
               .reindex(df.index, fill_value="Didn't answer"))
```

Output:

```
>>> df["ToD"]
0                            Didn't answer
1                       [Afternoon, Night]
2                                 Sporadic
3    [Morning, Afternoon, Night, Constant]
4                                    Night
Name: ToD, dtype: object
```

Comment: I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably prettier ways to do this but this would be one way:

```
def extract_valid_cols(row):
    # collect all non-"Didn't answer"-values in row
    valid_cols = [col for col in row if col != "Didn't answer"]  
    # return those, except when there are none, then return "Didn't answer"
    return valid_cols if valid_cols else ["Didn't answer"]

# apply the defined function row-wise
df["Time of the day"] = df.apply(extract_valid_cols, axis=1)

>          Morning  ...                        Time of the day
  0  Didn't answer  ...                        [Didn't answer]
  1  Didn't answer  ...                     [Afternoon, Night]
  2  Didn't answer  ...                             [Sporadic]
  3        Morning  ...  [Morning, Afternoon, Night, Constant]
  4  Didn't answer  ...                                [Night]
```

Putting everything in lists for consistency but if you really want single values then you can add a check if length of list is 1 and if it is just return that item.

Comment: Sporadic and Night values should be a scalar value not a list.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way

```
data = pd.DataFrame(d)

def summarize(x):
    if len(x.unique())==1:
        if x.unique()==["Didn't answer"]:
            return "Didn't answer"
    else:
        x = list(x.unique())
        x.remove("Didn't answer")
        return x

data.apply(summarize, axis  = 1)
```

Then you get:

```
0                            Didn't answer
1                       [Afternoon, Night]
2                               [Sporadic]
3    [Morning, Afternoon, Night, Constant]
4                                  [Night]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.apply` to get the data in the format you expect :

```
def get_values(row):
    row_set = set(row.values)
    if len(row_set) == 1:
        return (list(row_set)[0])
    elif("Didn't answer" in row_set):
        row_set.remove("Didn't answer")
        if(len(row_set) == 1):
            return (list(row_set)[0])
    return(list(row_set))

df["Time of the day"] = df.apply(get_values,axis=1)
```

This gives us the expected output :

```
0                            Didn't answer
1                       [Night, Afternoon]
2                                 Sporadic
3    [Night, Morning, Afternoon, Constant]
4                                    Night
```